# Session_Start not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, asp.net-2.0

We have a ASP.NET 2.0 website with some old classic asp pages on it. There is a login.asp page and home.aspx page. Login.asp page is redirected to the home.aspx for authenticated and authorized users.

We want to count the number of users visiting the site. If the user reaches some specified value, we are displaying some popup with some information. We are storing the Application variables on the global.asax file. Please fine the following code snipped for the global.asax

```
Protected Overloads Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Application("Count") = 0
End Sub

Protected Overloads Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)        
    Application("Count") = CInt(Application("Count"))+ 1        
End Sub
```

I am accessing the Application("Count") on the PageLoad method of Home.aspx.

When I open the browser with url `http://localhost/login.asp` and successfully login, the count never increases. If I go to `http://localhost/home.aspx`, the count increases. It looks like when login.asp redirects to the home.aspx, it doesn't call the session_start on the global.asax.

I am not very familiar with Classic asp. The end users always come from the login.asp.

What's the best way to access the correct incremented Application variable from global.asax file?

Comment: First of all I like to say you that this is not a good way to predict your users - the `application("count")`` refer to a static list that if not only one if you run your site on web garden. Also session start triggering and all spiders and robots, and users that did not allow cookies by default. Maybe alternative, but not better one, is to set a variable on the session, and if is not set then you increase the counter.

Comment: I dont see an obvious answer, it looks right but, you should know that if you are decementing the count in session_?End? (cant remember the name), it will take time before it will decrement. The seesion ends after X minutes of **inactivity** (x = SessionTimeout).

Comment: do you use `Session_Start` and `Session_End` for ***Count*** users ?

Comment: @Aristos don't you use `Session_Start` and `Session_End` for ***Count*** users ? WebFarm which best solution ? sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP pages are not processed by the ASP.Net engine. This means that it is correct that the Global.asax events are never fired for .asp urls.